# Swig wrap a c++ datatype?

Tags: python, c++, swig

This might be an easy question. How I can call c++ defined datatype **UInt32** from python?

test.cpp:

```
#include "test.h"
namespace test {  
    void test(UInt32 param) { std::cout << param << std::endl; }
}
```

test.h:

```
#include <ios>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <assert.h>
#include <cassert>
#include <cstddef>
#include <stddef.h>
namespace test {
    typedef std::uint32_t UInt32;
    void test(UInt32 param);
}
```

test.i:

```
%module test
%{
    #define SWIG_FILE_WITH_INIT
    #include "test.h"
%}
%include "test.h"
```

error:

```
>>> import test
>>> test.test(1)
TypeError: in method 'test', argument 1 of type 'test::UInt32'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that SWIG doesn't know what a type UInt32 "is." For a normal C++ typedef, you can simply tell SWIG in your interface file [using the `%typedef` command](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/SWIG.html#SWIG_nn20), e.g.:

```
%inline %{
 typedef unsigned int size_t;
%}
```

The above solution, i.e., `%apply int{ UInt32 };` is essentially [using the SWIG typemaps library](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/Arguments.html#Arguments_nn2) (`Typemaps.i`) to replace any instance of the argument of form `UInt32` with `int` (which SWIG knows about by default). However, it doesn't necessarily preserve the unsigned properties. Here you may want to instead use `%apply unsigned int { UInt32 };`. (Note that you need to include `Typemaps.i` for this to work).

Finally, if you need to be able to return the value (e.g., you want to pass it by reference), you can use the form:

```
%apply unsigned int *INOUT { UInt32 };
```

The way to go depends upon what you want to do. If you just need SWIG to understand a typedef as a "synonym" of a (primitive or derived) type SWIG already knows about, the `typedef` approach is sufficient. If you also need to control the behavior of how SWIG handles arguments (e.g., you need to be able to pass/return values by reference), typemaps (provided by the `%apply` command) is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Use typemapping ([link](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Typemaps.html#Typemaps_defining)).
The simplest should look like:

```
%apply int { test::UInt32 };
```